# How avoid to disable option when I select item

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

I use prime ng and i use p-multiselect. I need select only a value at time but I don't want use the prime ng default behavior that is when I select  option the other option are disabled and if I want change I need the unselect the selected item and I nedd choice another item. I want that when I check an item I can checked the other (but only one). this is my html code:

```
  <p-multiSelect [options]="listaIncarichi" [(ngModel)]="incaricoSelezionato" [selectionLimit]="1" [filter]="false"  ></p-multiSelect>
```

my .ts is:

```
 listI: SelectItem[];
  select item: string;

  constructor() {
    this.listI= [
      { label: 'A', value: 'A' },
      { label: 'U', value: 'U' }, { label: 'D', value: 'D' }
]
  }
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have the `[selectionLimit]` set to `1`. Try removing it and it should work.

Comment: i need to select only one option!

Comment: any solution for this yet?